# How to store a list of each user's items in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, row, query-optimization

If each user in a site can enter a comma-separated list of items that they type in (**not** from a pre-determined list!), how should we store that list for each user in MySQL so that items can be matched across users with the same items?

1. I know we shouldn't store the comma-separated string they've inputed as a `VARCHAR` in the DB, so how should it be stored?  Should a new table `ItemsList` be created where each row is a `UserID -> ItemName` (e.g. if user ID **101** enters "**Matches, Gun, Alcohol**", we would add 3 rows to `ItemsList` as `101 -> 'Matches', 101 -> Gun, 101 -> Alcohol`) ?
2. If so, what `PRIMARY KEY` should be used for that table?
3. What `indexes` should be set to make both the retrieval and matching of items as fast as possible?
4. Lastly, what query should be used to find all the users that have at least one Item in common with another user?

Comment: I think before you worry about the database schema, you have a few more questions to ask yourself. Is a free-form filed really the best option?  If yes, then how are you going to enforce data sanitization (i.e. so that different users don't put in `gun`, `Gun`, `GUN`, `guns`, `Guns`, etc. that could be logical matches but aren't string matches). If you don't plan on enforcing data sanitization, how do you plan to make matches out of things that are near-matches, if at all?

Comment: @MikeBrant:  I do plan on sanitizing, by making the list all lower case, then making the first letter of each word upper case, then exploding the list by comma, and trimming any spaces on the ends before storing them in the DB.  That said, I cannot think of any easy way to match singular vs. plural...

Answer (score 0):

Could you store the input as a JSON string in a TEXT column in the table? That way you can retrieve and display/update the JSON string whenever a user needs to add new items.  In doing this you aren't creating a new row for every single input. The Primary Key in this situation would be the user id, and as PKs are already indexes, you wouldn't need to create additional indexes.

Since the input will be comma-separated, you would do a split on commas into a list and then serialize the list as a JSON object (then store in DB).

Comment: Storing non-scalar data (such as JSON) in a row is *very bad* practice. How will you retrieve users having one "item" in common?

Comment: Queryable caching layer (Couchbase, for example) will allow you to find common key/values.  The root of this problem stems in having a user enter comma-separated values to begin with in my opinion.

Comment: @RyanMendoza: You said "*The root of this problem stems in having a user enter comma-separated values to begin with in my opinion*".  How would you recommend they enter items then, considering there is no pre-determined list since they can enter whatever they want?

Comment: My question was rather, how to do it with MySQL. My point is, with a RDBMS such as MySQL, resorting to [non-normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) layouts usually incur considerable overhead. Nevertheless, I definitely agree with your second point.

Comment: @YaK: I see you agree with Ryan's second point as well, so how would you recommend users enter their Items considering there is no pre-determined list?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. Assuming a table `ItemsList` with two columns `UserID` and `ItemName`, the primary key should be `(UserID, ItemName)` (both columns)
3. Besides the Primary Key, add an index on `ItemName`.
4. You are asking a bit too much. Please establish your final table structure, try something and come back with some code you have tried.

Comment: How do you set a Primary Key on 2 different columns?  How does that work and what value does it actually contain?  What happens if a user enters the same item two times (I'm assuming that would be prohibited by the Primary Key, so does that mean we would need to remove duplicated prior to insertion)?

Comment: 1. [See here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html). 2. Do you really want to allow the same item twice?

Comment: No, I do not, but I don't want the users to get a DB error if they do that, either, that's why I asked if we would have to remove any duplicates prior to insertion if we used a Primary Key on 2 different columns (which I assume we would).  I've never used a Primary Key on two columns, so I'm not familiar on how they work...